# Error during building the node source

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build the node source

```
vcbuild.bat release
```

When i execute the above command,

```
error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1
```

error is thrown.

The full error message is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [D:\nodesource\node-master\node_perfctr.vcxproj]
```

Comment: It has been a long while but I had a similar issue and this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300638/building-node-js-v0-10-12-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error is incorrectly generated node_js2c.vcxproj, where path to Python contains spaces and isn't quoted.
Fix - edit the file, and add quotes around path to the Python

call call **&quot;**C:\Program Files\python27\python.exe***&quot;* ...